# How to work around interaction between 'crossPaths := false' and '+publish'?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a build.sbt file where I have defined a sub-project that is java-only. So in that sub-project, I have set `crossPaths := false` so that the scala version is not included in artifact names.

That works as far as it goes, however, if I invoke `sbt +publish`, it runs the publish task for two versions of scala, and since it is ignoring scala version in artifact names, the publish is hitting an error on the second scala cross version, since artifacts of the same name were generated on the first version.

I can hack around it by allowing over-write on publish, but that is somewhat ugly since it is re-generating artifacts needlessly, and over-write can be unsafe for other reasons.

I'm looking for a way to do something logically equivalent to `skip in publish := false` for all scala versions except the first one, and specifically in the java sub-project, but not scala sub-projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added documentation for [Cross building with a Java project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Cross+building+with+a+Java+project).

> A special care must be taken when cross building involves pure Java project. Let’s say in the following example, `network` is a Java project, and `core` is a Scala project that depends on network.

```scala
lazy val scala212 = "2.12.8"
lazy val scala211 = "2.11.12"
lazy val supportedScalaVersions = List(scala212, scala211)

ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := scala212

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(network, core)
  .settings(
    // crossScalaVersions must be set to Nil on the aggregating project
    crossScalaVersions := Nil,
    publish / skip := false
  )

// example Java project
lazy val network = (project in file("network"))
  .settings(
    // set to exactly one Scala version
    crossScalaVersions := List(scala212),
    crossPaths := false,
    autoScalaLibrary := false,
    // other settings
  )

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .dependsOn(network)
  .settings(
    crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions,
    // other settings
  )
```

> 1. `crossScalaVersions` must be set to `Nil` on the aggregating projects such as the `root`.
> 2. Java subprojects should have exactly one Scala version in `crossScalaVersions` to avoid double publishing, typically `scala212`.
> 3. Scala subprojects can have multiple Scala versions in `crossScalaVersions`, but must avoid aggregating Java subprojects.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is arguably more of a workaround, but allows publishing and is relatively easy to understand:

In the top level project, you can set `configure(aggregate in publish := false)`. This allows most tasks to propagate to the java subproject as normal, but the publish task does not propagate, and so you can control publishing on a per-project basis. Now the java sub-project can be published exactly once by using `publish` instead of `+publish`:

```
sbt java_subproject/publish
sbt +top_level_project/publish
```

A drawback to this approach is that if you have multiple sub-projects, they would each need to be published individually:

```
sbt +sub_project_1/publish
sbt +sub_project_2/publish
...
sbt java_subproject/publish
sbt +top_level_project/publish
```

If you wanted to get fancy, you might insert a shim sub-project for any java subprojects, and make java projects a subproject of this shim, and then configure `aggregate in publish := false` on the shim. With this organization, you could do:

```
sbt java_shim_project/publish   // publish java projects exactly once
sbt +top_level_project/publish  // publish regular scala projects as usual
```